# method to change __be32 ip address into char in kernel space

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am making a module where I need to change the __be 32 format of address into char, which function could I use and under which header file it comes (I know to convert char to __be32 we use in_aton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For kernels older than 2.6.26(if not mistaken) you need to use the `NIPQUAD` macro, like:

```
pritk("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", NIPQUAD(your_b32_address));
```

For newer kernels a switch to `printk` was added:

```
printk("%pI4\n", your_b32_address);
```

Have a look here: http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-hacking/common-routines.html

Answer (score 1):

I would like to clarify that if you have

```
__be32 ipaddr;
```

you must pass the address of 'ipaddr' to printk

```
printk("%pI4\n", &ipaddr);
```